# How to change version of google app engine being used on server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have built my google app engine app using version 1.8.8 but the production server hosted by google uses 1.9.11. I think this may be causing problems within my app since my app works locally but not on the production server. Is there anyway to change the version of the sdk that the production server uses? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot define specifically which version of the SDK will run on the production servers. Typically, they run on the latest available SDK. If you are certain the that problems are caused due to the different versions of the SDK, I would propose to update your code accordingly.

Comment: With only a few small exceptions, all API versions (so far) are intended to be backwards compatible. If your app runs locally with one version but does not run locally with a later version, and the discrepancy wasn't announced well in advance with a deprecation warning, then that's a bug that should be reported.  If your app runs locally but not on App Engine, that might be due to inevitable discrepancies between the dev server (which only partially emulates the live server) and the live server. You can try upgrading your dev environment to rule out the version difference as a factor.